# Python DBAPI time out for connections?

Tags: python, python-db-api

I was attempting to test for connection failure,  and unfortunately it's not failing if the IP address of the host is fire walled.

This is the code:

```
def get_connection(self, conn_data):
    rtu, hst, prt, usr, pwd, db = conn_data  
    try:
        self.conn = pgdb.connect(host=hst+":"+prt, user=usr, password=pwd, database=db)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        return True
    except pgdb.Error as e:
        logger.exception("Error trying to connect to the server.")
        return False

if self.get_connection(conn_data):
    # Do stuff here:
```

If I try to connect to a known server but give an incorrect user name, it will trigger the exception and fail.

However if I try to connect to a machine that does not respond (firewalled) it never gets passed `self.conn = pgdb.connect()`

How to I wait or test for time out rather than have my app appear to hang when a user mistypes an IP address?

Comment: Spelling/grammar-nazi time: Pythobn -> Python, fire walled -> firewalled.   Oh, and the last line is not indented by four spacees, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is the pain of firewalls, and the timeout is the normal TCP timeout.

Comment: s/of firewalls/of stupid, "paranoid" firewalls/   It's actually the result of a DROP rule.  The proper way is to actually reply with a tcp-reset ICMP packet (IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

You can usually pass timeout argument in connect function. If it doesn't exist you could try with socket.timeout or [default timeout](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.setdefaulttimeout):

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(10) # sets timeout to 10 seconds
```

This will apply this setting to all connections(socket based) you make and will fail after 10 seconds of waiting.